# How to take screenshot of an image longer than screen from Visual Paradigm?

Tags: windows, screenshot

Is there a special tool for this? I have seen that the question is asked before but there is no answer. I think there must be a tool which can accomplish that? Otherwise I will have to take 10 screenshots and then merge them, will lose hours of time... I have windows7

I'm not trying to take screenshot of a web page, I have visual paradigm, and my sequence diagram is very long, when I want to export it as an image it has evaluation copy watermark on it, the license key I got from the University is not working...

Comment: It depends on what you want to screenshot. Some applications, like [Greenshot](http://getgreenshot.org/) support scrolling Internet Explorer windows to take screenshots of a full page. Similar features probably exist in other tools.

Comment: Could you describe what are you trying to do? Why would one want to take a screenshot of the image? Just copy the image. Why do you think it will take long to stitch screenshots? Even with 10 of them, you can do it in less then 5 minutes with decent graphical editor like Gimp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Faststone Capture](http://www.faststone.org/FSCaptureDetail.htm) software! According to me it is the best screen capture and editing tool,it can capture scrolling windows too that is all what you need!
read about it's all features!
it can easily and very fastly join 2 pictures vertically or horizontally!
If any query,then comment! :)

[image: Faststone Capture]

### Features

---

A small handy Capture Panel that provides quick access to its capture tools and output options
Global hotkeys to activate screen capturing instantly
Capture windows, objects, menus, full screen, rectangular/freehand regions and scrolling windows/web pages
Capture multiple windows and objects including multi-level menus
Record screen activities including onscreen changes, speech from microphone, mouse movements and clicks into highly compressed video files (Windows Media Video format). A built-in video editor allows you to draw annotations, apply zoom effects and cut unwanted sections
Options to specify output destination (internal editor, clipboard, file, printer ...)
Draw annotation objects such as texts, arrowed lines, highlights, watermarks, rectangles and circles
Apply effects such as drop-shadow, frame, torn-edge and fade-edge 
Add image caption
Resize, crop, rotate, sharpen, brighten, adjust colors ...
Undo/Redo
Support tabs that allow you to capture and edit multiple screenshots simultaneously 
Support external editors
Save in BMP, GIF, JPEG, PCX, PNG, TGA, TIFF and PDF formats
Acquire images from scanner
Convert images to a multi-page PDF file
Join images side by side to produce a single image file
Send captured images by email
Send captured images to Word and PowerPoint documents
Send captured images to a Web (FTP) server
Screen Color Picker
Screen Magnifier
Screen Crosshair
Screen Ruler
Support multiple monitors
Support touch interface (tap, swipe, pinch) 
Run when Windows starts (optional)
Minimize to System Tray area
Small footprint in memory
And many more ...

Comment: I think the output is a video when I scroll the window or? Plus I just need this tool once, does shareware version have limits and watermarks?

Comment: no, its full 30 days trial! no water marks!and the output is not a video its a long length pic,like 50x500 etc!give a try!read full features in site!
like If you want to take a screenshot of a web site.just click the browser it automatically scroll and capture,you can edit this in built in editor!Believe me it is the best screen capture tool i have ever seen!

Comment: It has a screen recorder with editor too! :)

Comment: Works like a charm, I would like to thank you so much!!!

Comment: Your Welcome :)